# stricly convex function implication.

Tags: limits, convex-analysis

I'm  work in the following statement

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a open convex set and  $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ a differential and strongly convex  function in  $\Omega$. Then  for each  $x \in \Omega$ and  $y \in \Omega$ such that  $x \neq y$
> \begin{equation*}
>    f(y)>f(x) +  \langle f^{\prime}(x), y-x\rangle. 
>   \end{equation*}

My attempt: Let $x,y \in D$ and $\alpha\in (0,1]$ e $d=y-x$, then form of stricly convexity of  $f$
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
     f(x + \alpha d)=& f(\alpha y + (1-\alpha)x)\\
         <& \alpha f(y)+(1-\alpha)f(x),
    \end{aligned}
   \end{equation*}
so
\begin{equation*}
   f(x +\alpha d)- f(x)<\alpha (f(y)-f(x)).
  \end{equation*}
Or
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned} 
  \displaystyle \lim_{\alpha \to 0^{+}}\frac{f(x +\alpha d)- f(x)}{\alpha}<  f(y)-f(x)
  \end{aligned}
 \end{equation*}
but the left hand side is $\langle f^{\prime}(x),d\rangle = \langle f^{\prime}(x),y-x \rangle$. Thus
\begin{equation}
\langle f^{\prime}(x),y-x \rangle \leq f(y)-f(x).
\end{equation}
But I need
\begin{equation}
\langle f^{\prime}(x),y-x \rangle < f(y)-f(x).
\end{equation}
not
\begin{equation}
\langle f^{\prime}(x),y-x \rangle \leq f(y)-f(x).
\end{equation}

Comment: Do you really mean "strongly convex" instead of "strictly convex"?

Comment: I want to say strictly convex.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to exclude equality case. Assume it holds you will have $$f(x)+\left\langle f'(x), y-x\right\rangle = f(y).$$

\begin{align}
f\left(\frac{x+y}2\right) &\ge f(x) + \left\langle f'(x), \frac{x+y}2 - x\right\rangle\\
&= f(x) + \frac{1}{2}\left\langle f'(x), y-x\right\rangle\\
&= \frac{f(x) + f(y)}{2} > f\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)
\end{align}

Which is a contradiction.